# Update opportunitylineitems inside an apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, update

I build inside a VF , a list of OpportunityLineItems using :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!productsList}" var="p">
   € <apex:inputField value="{!p.TotalPrice}" onchange="updateProd('{!p}');"/> (IVA Esclusa) (diconsi Euro{!p.PriceInLetter__c}) per :<br/>
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;<b>{!p.Product2.Name}</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<!--{!p.Description__c}--><apex:inputField type="text" value="{!p.Description__c}" onchange="updateProd('{!p}');"/>
     <br/>
     <br/>
```

Now what I'm tryng to do is update the OpportunityLineItems when the user modify the value of . I'm trying using js remoting but without success. This is my code:

```
script type="text/javascript">
         function updateProd(data){    
            var obj=data; //opp line item
            console.log('********The field value is ********'+obj);
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.OfferDetailPanelController.updateOppLineItems}',
                obj,
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {
                       console.log('SUCCESS');

                    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                        console.log('EXCEPTION');
                    } 
                },
                {escape: true}

            )


        }
     </script>



@RemoteAction
    global static void updateOppLineItems(Id obj) {
        System.debug('updateOppLineItems');
        System.debug('obj------>'+obj);
        System.debug([SELECT Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Description__c, ListPrice, TotalPrice, PriceInLetter__c
                       FROM OpportunityLineItem
                       WHERE Id =: obj]);
        update [SELECT Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, Description__c, ListPrice, TotalPrice, PriceInLetter__c
                       FROM OpportunityLineItem
                       WHERE Id =: obj];
    }
```

How can I update the opportunityLineItems when the user edit the inputField value?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values aren't going to make it back to the server, because merge fields are merged in real-time. Essentially, you're just updating the LastModifiedDate field and not actually saving any of the data. Personally, I'd use a wrapper for this.

---

```
public class OppLineWrapper {
  public OpportunityLineItem record { get; set; }
  public void save() {
    update record;
  }
}
```

---

```
<apex:repeat value="{!productsList}" var="p">
   € <apex:inputField value="{!p.record.TotalPrice}">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!p.save}" />
     </apex:inputField> (IVA Esclusa) (diconsi Euro{!p.PriceInLetter__c}) per :<br/>
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;<b>{!p.Product2.Name}</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<!--{!p.Description__c}-->
     <apex:inputField type="text" value="{!p.Description__c}">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!p.save}" />
     </apex:inputField>
     <br/>
     <br/>
```

---

You'll need to update your productsList variable to use the wrapper, and modify the code that populates the list to use the wrapper.